# Get C col if D is between two cols in another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Im kinda new to Python and Datascience.

I have a Dataset with 2 datetime columns `A` and `B` :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ["2019-03-13 08:12:20", "2019-03-15 10:02:18"], 'B': ["2019-03-13 08:12:25", "2019-03-13 10:02:20"], 'C': ['C1', 'C2']})
                     A                    B C
0  2019-03-13 08:12:20  2019-03-13 08:12:25 C1
1  2019-03-15 10:02:18  2019-03-13 10:02:20 C2
```

And a second dataset with like 500K+ rows with and i want to add `C` column to this dataset

To make it easier, let's say my second dataset have only one column `D`:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'D': ["2019-03-13 08:12:20", "2019-03-13 08:12:23", "2019-03-13 08:12:24", "2019-03-13 08:12:25", "2019-03-15 10:02:18", "2019-03-15 10:02:19", "2019-03-16 10:02:20"]})
                     D 
0  2019-03-13 08:12:20
1  2019-03-13 08:12:23
2  2019-03-13 08:12:24
3  2019-03-13 08:12:25
4  2019-03-15 10:02:18
5  2019-03-15 10:02:19
6  2019-03-16 10:02:20
```

For each row in D, i want to check the date and if its between A and B of the first dataset, i want to give the C value given in the first dataset.
And i want it to set C to NaN it its not between any A and B.

```
                     D  C
0  2019-03-13 08:12:20  C1
1  2019-03-13 08:12:23  C1
2  2019-03-13 08:12:24  C1
3  2019-03-13 08:12:25  C1
4  2019-03-15 10:02:18  C2
5  2019-03-15 10:02:19  C2
6  2019-03-16 10:02:20  NaN
```

I don't really how i can achieve this without using a regular loop and iterating over my second dataset..Can you please guys show me what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.IntervalIndex`, if available on your pandas, is helpful here:

```
df.A = pd.to_datetime(df.A)
df.B = pd.to_datetime(df.B)
s = df.set_index(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.A, df.B, closed='both'))['C']

df2['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['D']).map(s)
```

Output:

```
                     D    C
0  2019-03-13 08:12:20   C1
1  2019-03-13 08:12:23   C1
2  2019-03-13 08:12:24   C1
3  2019-03-13 08:12:25   C1
4  2019-03-15 10:02:18   C2
5  2019-03-15 10:02:19   C2
6  2019-03-16 10:02:20  NaN
```

Comment: Is there a shortcut to don't take the 6th like `6  2019-03-16 10:02:20  NaN` ? without make a `df.dropna()` ?

Comment: Use fillna instead of dropna, or replace instead of map.

Comment: I mean, i don't want to have the NaN row, i want to delete it, is there anything i can do instead of dropna ?

Comment: You could try playing with `isin`, but i'd settle with `dropna`.